# Using the scrollTo jQuery plugin with the Fancy Zomm jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox, scrollto

I'm trying to use the Fancy Zomm jQuery plugin to show multiple images in the same *lightbox* by using the scrollTo plugin to switch to the next of previous image which are all in different divs.

The problem is that it seams that I can't use jQuery inside the div displayed by the *lightbox*

Does anyone know how I could use the Fancy Zoom plugin to make a image gallery (similar to the original lightbox one)

I don't want to use another library, the look of Fancy Zoom is just what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found Fancybox which seams to do want I want so I think I'll use it instead of Fancy Zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Combining two different plugins may or may not work. It will help to give some links or some code trials. Plugins usually concentrate on doing one thing only, so making Fancy Zoom to do galleries is probably out of the question. On the other hand depending on which lightbox plugin are you using, it may be possible to attach zoom functionalities to the images from gallery.